FastAPI & React | AWS Lambda with function URL - 502 Bad Gateway
I've tried everything I can think of to get this working. My backend end is deployed on AWS Lambda. I'm using Mangum as a handler. I don't have any issues with any other API's except this one. I know the output format of a lambda function needs to be formatted like so:
{
"isBase64Encoded": true|false,
"statusCode": httpStatusCode,
"headers": { "headerName": "headerValue", ... },
"multiValueHeaders": { "headerName": ["headerValue", "headerValue2", ...], ... },
"body": "..."
}
When testing directly within AWS Lambda, I'm getting a 200 status code, and I'm getting all the image urls properly, however with my front end, I continue to get a 502 bad gateway. I've tried everything. I rewritten all of these functions in all the various ways. I've added logging. Im really confused on this one.
enter image description here
@router.get("/images/{vin_number}")
async def get_vehicle_images(vin_number: str):
    try:
        image_urls = s3.get_vehicle_images(vin_number)

        response_content = {
            "isBase64Encoded": False,
            "statusCode": 200,
            "headers": {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
            "body": json.dumps(image_urls)
        }
        return JSONResponse(content=response_content, status_code=200)

    except Exception as e:
        response_content = {
            "isBase64Encoded": False,
            "statusCode": 500,
            "headers": {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
            "body": json.dumps({"message": "Internal server error"})
        }
        return JSONResponse(content=response_content, status_code=500)


Below is one method from a class I made using boto3.
    def get_vehicle_images(self, vin_number: str):
        s3_client = self.init_boto3_session()

        images = []
        prefix = f"static/uploads/{vin_number}/vehiquo/"
        distibution_domain = self.distribution_domain
        key_pair_id = "KSHTGXKE0S9KB"
        signer = CloudFrontSigner(key_pair_id, self.rsa_signer)
        
        expires_in = timedelta(hours=1)
        expiration_time = datetime.now() + expires_in
        
        for obj in s3_client.Bucket(self.bucket_name).objects.filter(Prefix=prefix):
            file_key = obj.key
            resource_url = f"https://{distibution_domain}/{file_key}"
            signed_url = signer.generate_presigned_url(
                resource_url,
                date_less_than=expiration_time
            )
            images.append(signed_url)
        return images

This is my function to fetch the images from my backend.
export async function getVehicleImages(vin) {
  if (!vin) {
    throw new Error("VIN is required to fetch vehicle images");
  }

  const URL = `${BASE_URL}/vehicles/images/${vin}`;
  const accessToken = await retrieveToken();

  try {
    const response = await fetch(URL, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      credentials: "include",
    });

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(`Error fetching vehicle images: ${response.statusText}`);
    }

    const lambdaResponse = await response.json();
    if (lambdaResponse.statusCode !== 200) {
      throw new Error(`Server responded with an error: ${lambdaResponse.body}`);
    }

    const images = JSON.parse(lambdaResponse.body);
    return images;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error fetching vehicle images: ${error.message}`);
    throw error; 
  }
}

This is just a portion of my React component.
function UnitData({ unit, isLoading, vinNumber }) {
  const [currentImageIndex, setCurrentImageIndex] = useState(0);
  const [imageURLs, setImageURLs] = useState([]);
  const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchVehicleImages() {
      try {
        const images = await getVehicleImages(vinNumber);
        setImageURLs(images);
      } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(`Error fetching vehicle images: ${error.message}`);
      }
    }
    if (vinNumber) {
      fetchVehicleImages();
    } else {
      throw new Error("VIN is required to fetch vehicle images");
    }
  }, [vinNumber]);
...
...

I've attempted as much as I could on my own before coming here. See above for details.
